# fetching result from database in specific format cakephp5

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

I am currently in the process of migrating from CakePHP 2.8 to CakePHP 5.x. In CakePHP 2.8, I used to retrieve results in the following format:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('UserDetail'),
));

Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )
        
    [UserDetail] => Array
       (
            [id] => 1
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
       )
)
```

However, after migrating to CakePHP 5.0, the results are now in the following format:

```
    (
    (
        [id] => 83
        [field1] => value1
        [field2] => value2
        [field3] => value3
        [user_detail] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )
    )
)

$query  = $this->find('all')->contain(['UserDetail']);
$result = $query->toArray();
```

Is there a way to retrieve the results in CakePHP 5.x in the same format as in CakePHP 2.8?

Thank you for any assistance in this CakePHP 5.x migration from 2.x.

Comment: There are probably things you could do to make it come in this format. Having gone through the upgrade process myself, let me tell you that you don't actually want to do that. Any time that you will save in not needing to update algorithms and templates you will more than lose in trying to build and maintain this. Better to bite the bullet and fully embrace the entity structure ASAP.